# How to verify Stripe Webhook Signature manually using JSON JQ Expressions?

Tags: json, stripe-payments, jq, webhooks, digital-signature

I am trying to verify webhook signature for certain webhook events for Stripe Application, but I am getting -

```
401 - Unauthorized  No valid API key provided.
```

Below is my PolicyInbound [security policy for webhook] for Stripe -

```
"policyInbound": {
      "type": "managed",
      "policy": "DIGITAL_SIGNATURE",
      "securityProperties": [
        {
          "name": "signatureFunction",
          "displayName": "Signature Statement",
          "hidden": true,
          "required": true,
          "fixed": "\"sha256=\"+connectivity::hex(connectivity::HMAC(\"SHA256\"; .securityProperties.secret;  .request.headers.\"stripe-signature\" + .request.body))"
        },
        {
          "name": "signatureLocation",
          "displayName": "Request Signature Location",
          "hidden": true,
          "required": true,
          "fixed": ".request.headers.\"stripe-signature\""
        },
        {
          "name": "signKey",
          "displayName": "secret",
          "hidden": false,
          "required": true
        }
      ]
    }
```

Below is my Trigger for Event Subscription -

```
"CreateCustomerTrigger": {
  "displayName": "Subscribe to a Create Customer event",
  "description": "This trigger detects when an event has been raised.",
  "group": "simple",
  "type": "webhook",
  "httpMethod": "POST",
  "request": {
    "schemaType": "application/json",
    "schema": {
      "$ref": "#/schemas/CustomerCreationResponseBodySchema"
    }
  },
  "webhook": {
    "headers": [
      {
        "name": "stripe-signature",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "user-agent",
        "type": "string"
      }
    ],
    "body": {
      "schemaType": "application/json",
      "schema": {
        "$ref": "#/schemas/CustomerCreationResponseBodySchema"
      }
    }
  },
  "subscription": {
    "register": "flow:CreateAWebhookEndpointFlow",
    "deregister": "flow:DeleteAWebhookEndpointFlow"
  }
}
```

Below is my Webhook Subscription Flow -

```
"CreateAWebhookEndpointFlow": {
  "id": "CreateAWebhookEndpointFlow",
  "version": "0.1",
  "start": "startState",
  "specVersion": "0.8",
  "functions": [
    {
      "name": "CreateAWebhookEndpointFunction",
      "operation": "connectivity::rest",
      "type": "custom"
    }
  ],
  "states": [
    {
      "actions": [
        {
          "functionRef": {
            "refName": "CreateAWebhookEndpointFunction",
            "arguments": {
              "uri": "https://api.stripe.com/v1/webhook_endpoints?enabled_events[0]=customer.created&url={url}",
              "method": "POST",
              "headers": "${ .input.headers }",
              "parameters": {
                "url": "${xyz_url}"
              }
            }
          },
          "actionDataFilter": {
            "results": "${ { body: .body, headers: .headers } }",
            "toStateData": "${ .output }"
          }
        }
      ],
      "name": "startState",
      "type": "operation",
      "end": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Please suggest me how can I provide JSON JQ to verify Stripe Signature with respect to any Integration URL of Workato, Dellboomi or Celigo.

Comment: Can you share your code that throws the error you're reporting?

Comment: @jonathan Steele we are not writing any code for this. We just write above mentioned JQ expressions in JSON file and in backend SDK handles rest part. So we dont code anything here.

Comment: Ok, but what is the 'backend SDK' that you're referring to? Somewhere you must be using a Stripe library to try and construct an event from the payload.